# What is the general structure of an automation framework built in Selenium Java Cucumber BDD?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework

I am a complete newbie in **Selenium** and test automation. What is a general structure of `Java` **Automation Test**, using a Behavior-Driven Development (BDD) framework in `Cucumber`.

Additionally, could you explain the **Automation Framework** (AF)'s components ?
Could you also share an overview *example* of implementing a test class (and its utilities), which is used in the Tech. industry?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Seeing as this is such an open ended question and how new to this you say you are, it might just be best to look up some tutorials or trainings and follow those. I doubt many people will be sharing complete automation frameworks here.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I just need a little overview of Framework design that is used in Real-time projects by organisations.

Comment: I dont see any good material, sites, books on how to design an Automation framework...there are tons of resources on Selenium API, POM but not about Framework designing as  it is.

Comment: @tester232 For StackExchange's site, I would suggest you being more precise on your question. I would suggest for you to explain your context - business mission, testing mission, resources, people -, to explain what you have done so far, and what difficulties are you facing. With this, people will be able to give precise suggestions you can apply to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "general structure for any framework". Frameworks are meant to be custom made as per the type/or need of the project. Having said that, I think I understand what you are looking for. Follow the you-tube tutorial series in link below for the framework implementation using selenium(java binding) and BDD(cucumber) framework. This guy has explained it really well. I suggest, after watching the video, download the source code from git and try to implement in your local setup. Good luck.

[Link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHzMJuc9Zuk)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will follow the playlist.

Comment: In stack overflow, you thank by either upvoting the answer(if the answer is useful) or by accepting it if it has answered your question. This will help others who are trying to find an answer for similar questions.

Answer (score -1):

When creating a Test Automation Framework, we should consider the following main points:

- To be able to create automated tests quickly by using appropriate abstraction layers
- The framework should have meaningful logging and reporting structure
  Should be easily maintainable and extendable
- Should be simple enough for testers to write automated tests
  A retry mechanism to rerun failed tests
- This is especially useful for WebDriver UI tests
- Framework structure could be like below:

[image]

I borrow details from [here](https://artoftesting.com/selenium-java-automation-framework)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What all utilities classes do you use in your framework?

Comment: I am using utility classed as helpers. That includes separate class for web action or interaction, browser controls, element finder with different methods, test data generation, groovy file, report generation and publishing to diff sources etc